# Access a puppet class variable dynamically

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to dynamically access a variable in a class? For example:

```
class namespace::hello() {
    $cow = "moo"
    $dog = "bark"
}

$dynamic = 'cow'
$value = $namespace::hello::[$dynamic]  # doesn't work
```

I'm doing this because I have classes defined with variables in them for each environment, e.g.:

```
class company::env::production {
    $dns = "1.2.3.4"
}

class company::env::office {
    $dns = "2.3.4.5"
}
```

Comment: So, you're trying to dynamically reference either `company::env::production` or `company::env::office` based on which environment the node is in?  I'd like to understand a little more of what you're trying to do with this, but I don't think this kind of class structure is a good solution.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Yes, basically. Throughout the code I would like to access the environment settings, i.e. the `$dns` variable, depending on what the `node` is declared as. What alternatives would you suggest?

Comment: It could be as simple as just doing a `case` check against the dynamic variable (`$environment`?) to set the `$dns` variable instead of putting them in different classes.  But as Ger mentioned in your answer below, using Hiera is probably your best option if you have the ability to switch over to using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a nasty solution. I hope someone can give me a better alternative.

By using `inline_template` with `scope.lookupvar`, you can reference a dynamic variable:

```
inline_template("<%= scope.lookupvar('$namespace::hello::${dynamic}') %>")
```

**Update**

Because of the complexity of the solution, I just made a hack on top of that hack. I made a custom function that's does that one liner:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:config, :type => :rvalue) do |arguments|

    if arguments.size != 2
      raise(Puppet::ParseError, "config(): 2 args required)")
    end

    env = arguments[0]
    var = arguments[1]

    lookupvar("::company::env::#{env}::#{var}")
  end
end
```

And in  your `.pp`:

```
$dns_server = config("production", "dns_server")
```

Comment: You desperately need Hiera, although this hack might fix your problem now, it will haunt you sometime in the future...

Comment: @GerApeldoorn Yes, I am definitely worried about raptors (reference: http://xkcd.com/292/). Thanks, I will check out hiera.